# How to perform a post-hoc test on the lmer model when the data is very large

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, post-hoc

I'm trying to do post hoc for my lmer model. My fixed effects are all continuous variables. I tried the `emtrends()` function in the 'emmeans' package.

`emtrends(fm_final, pairwise ~ Freq_SCALE, var="WORD_LENGTH_SCALE")`

It gives me this warning.

```
Note: D.f. calculations have been disabled because the number of observations exceeds 3000.
To enable adjustments, add the argument 'pbkrtest.limit = 102411' (or larger)
[or, globally, 'set emm_options(pbkrtest.limit = 102411)' or larger];
but be warned that this may result in large computation time and memory use.
Note: D.f. calculations have been disabled because the number of observations exceeds 3000.
To enable adjustments, add the argument 'lmerTest.limit = 102411' (or larger)
[or, globally, 'set emm_options(lmerTest.limit = 102411)' or larger];
but be warned that this may result in large computation time and memory use.
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
Error in if ((misc$estType == "pairs") && (paste(c("", by), collapse = ",") !=  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Since it says the number of observations exceeds the limitation, I then run the following code.

```
emtrends(fm_final, pairwise ~ Freq_SCALE, var="WORD_LENGTH_SCALE", pbkrtest.limit = 102411,lmerTest.limit = 102411)
```

However, there is another warning.

```
Error in t(ZZ) %*% EE %*% ZZ : 
  Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 146
```

I have also tried other computers, but there is no help. Are there any suggestions on how can I do posthoc please?

Comment: You could try adding `mode = "asymp"` to the call to disable the fancy calculations needed by the K-R method. You will get z tests instead of t tests, but those should be all right unless you have small numbers of subjects.

Comment: @RussLenth Thank you for your reply. I tried what you said, but there was an error: `NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
Error in if ((misc$estType == "pairs") && (paste(c("", by), collapse = ",") !=  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`
Do you know how to fix this error when I only have numeric predictors?

Comment: Upgrade to version 1.7.2, just now on CRAN. The first message is just a warning, but you really should be careful when averaging over factors that interact. The second is due to a logic error in the summarizing code, and it is fixed in the new version.

Comment: PS you could save a whole huge amount of computation by doing `EMM = emtrends(...)` (the first one in the question) and then `pairs(EMM)`. Your second call repeats all of the computations that went into EMM. What predictors interact with `Freq_SCALE` besides `WORD_LENGTH_SCALE`? The trends you have estimated depend on the values of those, and with your code you are only looking at when they are at their means (if continuous) or averaged over factor levels (if factor).

Comment: @RussLenth I have upgraded to version 1.7.2, and the error in the if function is no longer displayed. My linear model is `fm_final<- lmer(response ~ Freq_SCALE*WORD_LENGTH_SCALE+ (1 | subjects) + (1 |trail_no) , data = data1, REML = TRUE )`. There are 102411 valid data.

Comment: I tried the method you said `EMM <- emtrends(test, ~ Freq_SCALE, var = "WORD_LENGTH_SCALE", mode = "asymp", pbkrtest.limit = 102411, lmerTest.limit = 102411)`, then `pairs(EMM)` and the result is like this: `contrast  estimate SE df z.ratio p.value
                (nothing)   nonEst NA NA      NA      NA
                Degrees-of-freedom method: asymptotic `.

Comment: If I exclude it, it gives me an error: `Error in t(ZZ) %*% EE %*% ZZ : 
  Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 146 `. Do you have any suggestions? Is there another way to do the post hoc or to do it manually?

Comment: If you hadn't run out of memory, you'd have gotten NAs this way too. I surmise you have empty cells in your data, and that leads to non estimable cells. You may be able to get results if you remove some interactions. Remember my warning earlier about those? There is only so much help you can get here, and I suggest you could benefit greatly from talking to a statistical consultant. Many university stat and biostatistics departments have some sort of service or ways to connect you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the methodology implemented by emtrends, and its help page is somewhat deficient describing what it actually does, so this answer doesn't come with any guarantee (I had a look at this though: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html#covariates ). It may help you, but it isn't really a complete answer.

Anyway, what I believe is this: The test is based on the t-distribution. If the number of degrees of freedom of the t-distribution converges to infinity, the t-distribution converges to the normal distribution (which doesn't have degrees of freedom), and the t-distribution with a large df is very accurately approximated by a normal distribution. For this reason, the test can probably be computed based on the normal distribution without requirement to compute the df, and chances are it will be accurate also then, so I don't think anything needs to be done about the warning, unless you need to computation of the df for other reasons than just running the text.

Note however also that this is my interpretation of the "Warning" only, but it seems there is also an "Error", on which I can't tell you anything. (Generally warnings in R are things to note regarding the results that you get, whereas errors stop you from getting results. My impression is that the warning may not be problematic, but the error is, and it may have to do with your input object, which of course I don't know.)